# Focus management with browser API instead of ref in React app?

Tags: reactjs, focus

I need to manage focus in my React app. I need to listen for an event in a parent and focus on a deeply nested child component.

I know best practice is to use a ref but this is proving complicated. Sadly our app is quite messy, lots of indirection through nested components, Redux forms, etc.

Simply using `getElementById` outside of React is much less code and works fine for me:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const elem = document.getElementById('child-input-ID');
    elem.focus();
  }
```

However is this a robust solution? A colleague told me that due updates via the virtual DOM this method could be unreliable, but I think I saw Marcy Sutton doing it this way on her FrontEnd Masters course: https://frontendmasters.com/courses/javascript-accessibility/

Comment: FocusManager: https://embed.plnkr.co/e4eUC1/

Answer (score 0):

If many nested components are the biggest obstacle, maybe you can use `context API` to pass `ref`? All of those ideas will contribute to tech debt, so try refactoring as soon as possible. Fixing React code base is sometimes easier than it seems at first.

Comment: Even if it's purely for my own interest, could you tell me what the issue with my solution is? You have to make sure #child-input-ID matches but there are ways of doing that.